# commands to add additional environment variable in mpirun

Tags: mpi

When running:

```
mpirun -x PATH -n 8 ./myprogramme
```

It seems the PATH variable would be replaced by the PATH we specified. However, what if we only want to add into the PATH variable other than replacing it. What command shall we use? Thank you.

Comment: Why wouldn't `mpirun -x "/new/location/bin:$PATH" -n 8 ./myprogramme` do the job?  Or add the new location at the end after your current path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MPI does not support this functionality. You can however use a workaround by passing the `$PATH` through a remote `bash` shell.

To do so, run:

```
mpirun -np 8 "/bin/bash -c 'PATH=$PATH:\$PATH && ./myprogramme'"
```

Note that `$PATH` is the path where `mpirun` is executed, and `\$PATH` is the default path on the target node. This command first starts `bash` on the remote node, sets the new path variable there, and then executes the program in the remote bash environment.